# jquery toggle not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

My Jscript/Jquery is not working. I can alert but I cannot get my div to toggle. Can someone explain to me why please? My code is below. I am using JSP if it matters.

My Javascript

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    $(".moreButtonClass").click(function(e){
        var id = this.id;
        var cleanid = id.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
        var dog = "post" + cleanid;
        alert(dog);
        $(dog).toggle();
    });
});
```

My Html

```
<div id="content">
    <h1>Site Update Log:</h1>
<% for(int i = 0; i<2; i++){ %>
    <div class="blogPost" id="postGroup<%= i %>">
        <div>The ID is :<%out.print(indexModel.miniBlogConnector.GetID(i));%></div>
        <div>The DATE is :<%out.print(indexModel.miniBlogConnector.GetDate(i));%></div>
        <div>The AUTHOR is :<%out.print(indexModel.miniBlogConnector.GetAuthor(i));%></div>
        <div>The MINIPOST is :<%out.print(indexModel.miniBlogConnector.GetShortPost(i));%></div>
        <div class="MainPost" id="post<%=i%>">The POST is :<%out.print(indexModel.miniBlogConnector.GetPost(i));%></div>
        <button type="button" class="moreButtonClass" id="moreButton<%=i%>">more</button>
    </div>
<% } %>
</div> <!-- end #content -->
```

My CSS

```
.MainPost {
    display:none;
}
```

Can anyone please explain to me why I can alert dog and get the correct variable name. But when I try to toggle it; it is not functioning. Nothing happens. No errors; no changes. It absolutely does nothing. I even tried using console.log and was unable to get it to react. The button works because the alert works; but the toggle is not functioning.

Can any one let me know how to fix this please?

Comment: Do you include the `#` in yout selector string(dog)?

Comment: I can't believe it. Thank you so much. I have been working on this for over an hour. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `dog` is just a variable, and not a DOM node.

You need to do:

```
$("#"+dog).toggle(); //assuming it is an id. if class, use . instead of  #
```

Comment: I up arrowed you as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the content in the `dog` is an ID, use this:

```
$("#" + dog).toggle();
```

Or, if it is a class, use this:

```
$("." + dog).toggle();
```

Since, in your case, it is going to be an ID, you need to use the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the selector `#` here.Then it will consider as a variable not DOM element

```
var dog = "#post" + cleanid;
        $(dog).toggle();
```

or

```
$("#"+dog).toggle();
```

Comment: The site says you were the first to post. I will accept your answer after my cool down passes and it allows me to do so. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Aaron Check again who posted first! :P